# What do the parameters in the toArray method do?

Tags: java, arrays

I am not exactly sure what the parameters in the `toArray` method do and what its function is. Suppose I had the following code:

```
Integer array [][] = new Integer[testing.size()][];

    for (int y = 0; y < testing.size(); y++)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> testing2 = square.get(y);
        array[y] = testing2.toArray(new Integer [testing2.size()]);
    }       
}
```

`Square` is a multidimensional array list. Why does `array[y]` look like a single dimensional array when it was declared as a 2d array. Also, what does this parameter`(new Integer [testing2.size()])` do in this situation? Sorry if my question is unclear.

Comment: The Java docs go over the `toArray` call: [`Collection#toArray(T[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(T[])). Basically, it puts all the elements of the `ArrayList` into an array, allowing you to specify the size and type of the array.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does array[y] look like a single dimensional array when it was declared as a 2d array.

`array[y]` is a single dimensional array.  Your `array` is a 2d array, and when you provide 1 index it is a 1d array and when you provide 2 indecies, it is just a scalar value.

> what does this parameter(new Integer [testing2.size()]) do in this situation?

It provides an array of a sufficient size (or at least an appropriate type) to populate.

If you want to know what a method does, I suggest reading the Javadoc.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray(T%5B%5D)

The array to pass is;

> the array into which the elements of this list are to be stored, if it is big enough; otherwise, a new array of the same runtime type is allocated for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

In `Java` 2D array is an array of arrays. Therefore each row of the array could have different size.

```
Integer array [][] = new Integer[testing.size()][];

    for (int y = 0; y < testing.size(); y++) {
        // list of integers
        List<Integer> testing2 = square.get(y);
        // create an 1D array from the list
        Integer[] testingArray = testing2.toArray(new Integer [testing2.size()]);
        // add this 1D array to the row y of the based array (1D + 1D array == 2D array)
        array[y] = testingArray;
    }       
}
```

**P.S.**

```
int[][] arr = new int[2][];  // create 2D array with 2 rows (colums not defined)
arr[0] = new int[3];         // row 0 is now an array with 3 elements (columns)
arr[1] = new int[5];         // row 1 is now an array with 5 elements (columns)

int a = int[1][4];  // row 1, column 4
int b = int[0][4];  // ArrayOutOfBoundException

int[] row = int[0]; // retrieve whole row 0 as 1D array with 3 elements (columns)
```

Comment: To help clarify: array[0] is an array of length "testing2.size()". array[1] is a different array, which might have a different length from array[0]. Don't think of Java arrays as mathematical arrays--they are, as Oleg says, 1D arrays of 1D arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass an array of the correct or greater size, it can be filled and returned.
Otherwise a new array is created, filled and returned.

IN fact, the parameter is mostly there because otherwise, there is no way for the method toArray() to know what is the type of array that it has to return.
This is a consequence of type erasure and the unability to say `new T[]`. Because you pass an array, it is possible within the method to create a new instance by using reflection on the passed object.